# .png to .svg without losing colors

Tags: vector, svg, png

Does anybody know how to convert a .png (transparent background) image to a .svg vector image (transparent background) without losing colors of the original .png? I have looked at multiple solutions on Internet, and tried many, but not successful yet.

So if anybody does that already, it would be great to know.

**edit**: Thank you for your replies. Please see this image. When I create a svg  using different solutions, I want to be able to get the same image with a transparent background. Instead most of the solutions I found (desktop apps) create the rectangular block of bluish color, when I open it in Aurora 3d logo animation software. Some solutions allow me to create only borders of the logo below, but then I do not understand how to fill color in it the way I want in Aurora 3d software. These images open up with colors in Inkspace, but the moment I import svg into Aurora I do not get the same effect.

I am attaching some screenshots in aurora 3d software after importing the svg.

[image]

[image]

Edit: Thank you very much CFS. I am able to create a separate colored svg as per your steps, however, when I import that in Aurora 3d, I still do not get colors. I get the following. Why I am still not getting colors?

Also, I would not like to have that rectangular frame covering the logo, but only logo, and I tried some settings in Inkspace to have only logo, and no surrounding frame, but was not successful.

[image]

edit: Hi Cai. thank you for your reply. Yes, I noticed that about Aurora and tried coloring the object, but I think a problem is the way I can unlink "break" individual objects in inkspace, in Aurora, the entire SVG is a single object, and even though I am trying to ungroup / edit svg, it still applies any transformation (like fill color) to the entire SVG than only a single object. I am trying to see how can I edit individual objects in Aurora now. Example attached. 
[image]

Comment: Is your monitor calibrated to sRGB IEC61966?

Comment: What is the main issue you're having with the colors? Can you [edit your answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/75897/edit) to post some screenshots so we can see what's happening?

Comment: Hi Mrunal, welcome to GD.SE. Please note that we are a Question and Answer site, and not a forum. If you have additional information for your existing question, please use [edit] as you have. But if the new information is a follow-up or a different question, please post a new question. You can link to this one for context. Also, please have a look at the [help] to better understand what this site is about. Thanks!

Comment: This question keeps changing all the time! so in the end your issue is not converting a PNG to SVG, but importing SVG to Aurora 3D? Sounds like you should [read the user guide](http://www.presentation-3d.com/onlinehelp/Aurora%203D%20Text%20and%20Logo%20Maker.pdf) before asking a question here.

Comment: Yes, Vincent. Thanks much for the information. Luciano, I did not know where the problem was in the beginning when I started, and then I kept on editing with new information as progressed, so the question kept on changing.

Comment: Inkscape has now (As of Dec 2017) the option to trace bitmap with colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can trace the PNG with the trace bitmap option in Inkscape.  Then choose to break apart.  Both these options are under the PATH menu.  This will give you a black SVG which you can then set the colours for on each of the objects.  Then save as an SVG in inkscape.

If you have problems with detecting the elements of the PNG you may need to trace twice with different brigtness or edge detection and then reassemble.

Answer (score 0):

As [CF5 answered](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/75951/52050), you can use the trace bitmap function in Inkscape to get your SVG shapes, but you will need to color the shapes in Aurora 3d.

If you look through the help documentation on [importing SVG](http://www.presentation-3d.com/how-to-import-svg-aurora-3d-text-logo-maker.html) and read through the [usr guide (PDF)](http://www.presentation-3d.com/onlinehelp/Aurora%203D%20Text%20and%20Logo%20Maker.pdf) it seems that it is only the path data that is imported, not any color attributes. Set the color of your object by selecting the object in the Render window and selecting the Color tab in the Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

So just in case some body finds this post useful in future, here is an answer that I received from Aurora 3d team for setting different colors to different parts of the svg. Adding here as a separate answer. This is not available in their documentation.

If you want set different color for the different part of the SVG. You can duplicate the svg, and edit it, remove some part.

Then you can split the svg to different parts, and set different color for them. Finally, you can make them to a group.